# How to dynamically add HTML <meta> tags to the html <HEAD> element using Apache Tiles

Tags: facebook, spring-mvc

I'm working on a website that displays a list of products and each of them displays a facebook like button. During testing I noticed that every time I hit the like button my facebook wall was not showing any info about my site or the product's image so I figured this had to do with facebook's [Open Graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Since I'm creating the web pages for the products dynamically using Spring MVC and Apache Tiles, **how do I insert these meta tags dynamically**??

```
<meta property="og:title" content="book for sale" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/product/1111" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mysite.com/pics/230980048.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="mysite.com" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="31536131" />
```

Is this something that needs to be done on tiles templates (`tiles-definitions`)?

I was thinking at first that I needed to write them on the spring controller using the `HttpServletResponse` parameter.

Then I thought there was a jsp tag that could insert meta tags, sort of like `<jsp:meta>`

As you may see I'm lost, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using tiles attributes with [expression language](http://tiles.apache.org/2.1/framework/tutorial/advanced/el-support.html), on my template I have:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />        
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="meta" ignore="true" />
</head>
```

Then, on my tiles-definitions file I have

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition extends="default" name="myView">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/myView.jspx" />
        <put-attribute name="meta" expression="${metaTags}"/>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

Finally, on my spring web controller I have:

```
uiModel.addAttribute("metaTags", createMetaTags(item) );
```

Where `createMetaTags` builds the string for the meta tags dynamically.

**Make sure** you have tiles-el.jar in your classpat n order for this to work.